# Rearranging the Table Data with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which each row is a widget with the alternate css class `.odd` & `.even` and inside the each widget there are four columns.

The structure looks like :

[image]

Is there any way to rearrange these data in the following format with apply the css to `<td>` ?

[image]

Here is my fiddle code :  [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/2sTjp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sTjp/17/)

```
.test td {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure try adding the following CSS:

```
tr td {
    display: block;  
    margin-left: 170px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2sTjp/14/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `inline-block` for the table columns.

```
.odd td,.even td{padding-left:80px;display:inline-block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sTjp/16/)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve desire result by giving `float:right` and using some `width`. Check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/2sTjp/18/)**.

```
td{word-break:break-word; float:right; width:100px; }
```